# Visual Studio 17.8, I do not see .NET 8.0 as a option for Blazor Server project template

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I have installed Visual Studio 17.8, but do not see .NET 8.0 as a option for Blazor Server.
I do see it as a option for Blazor Web App.
I can't understand this behaviour, installed it, uninstalled it, repaired it.
But still no .NET 8 on Blazor Server project template.

I be grateful for the help.

I have tried Everything

Answer (score 8):

There is no Blazor Server template in .NET 8

Quoted from [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/49446#issuecomment-1638302546)

> There is no Blazor Server template in .NET 8.0. It's been subsumed/unified into the Blazor Web template. You should be able to get the same Blazor Server experience if you select Blazor Web + Server components.

Also mentioned in the [release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-6/#blazor-template-consolidation)

> As part of unifying the various Blazor hosting models into a single model in .NET 8, we’re also consolidating the number of Blazor project templates. In this preview release we’ve removed the Blazor Server template and the “ASP.NET Core hosted” option from the Blazor WebAssembly template. Both of these scenarios will be represented by options when using the new Blazor Web App template.